# What did I forget to include?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to initialize ngBootbox and toaster.

```
 var app, deps;

            deps = ['treeGrid'];

            app = angular.module('MyApp', deps);

            app.controller('treeGridController', [
                '$scope', '$http', '$ngBootbox', 'toaster',
                function($scope, $http, $ngBootbox, toaster, $timeout) {
..some code
}]);
```

And I get this error in the console :

> [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $ngBootboxProvider <- $ngBootbox

What did I forget to install? I have a similar page and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `ngBootbox` and `toaster` into your module dependencies, like this:

```
deps = ['ngBootbox', 'toaster', 'treeGrid']
```